# Top N mostly used in huge list

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I was given a task to find the most commonly used strings in a huge file (gigabytes). I wrote the following spark program to create RDD in the file.

```
val conf = new Sparkconf()      //initializing sparkConf
val sc = new SparkContext(conf) //initializing SparkContext
val input = sc.textfile("..../input path")   //load the input path
val words = input.flatMap(line=>line.split(""))   //split by words
val counts = words.map(word=>(word, reducebyKey{case(x,y) => x+y})     //reducebykey to count the number of repeating words
val topcount = counts.top(5)                    //select top 5
```

However, this top 5 is not fetching me the most used. Only returning the top elements after flatmap.

Comment: If I may, to parse a single file (even gigabytes), spark is very probably totally overkill, and good old bash is often a one liner fast solution.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the count of each word , sort it in descending order .

```
val conf = new Sparkconf() //initializing sparkConf 
val sc = new SparkContext(conf) //initializing SparkContext 
val input = sc.textfile("..../input path") //load the input path 
val words = input.flatMap(line=>line.split("")) //split by words 
val wordCounts = words.map(x => (x, 1)).reduceByKey( (x,y) => x + y ) //to count the number of repeating words
//Flip (word, count) tuples to (count, word) and then sort by key (the counts)
val wordCountsSorted = wordCounts.map( x => (x._2, x._1) ).sortByKey(false,1) 
val topcount = wordCountsSorted.top(5) //select top 5
```

After reduceByKey opeteratin , we get a rdd[(word , count)] i.e. something like [("we",5)] . After that , we are fliping the key value pair in wordCountsSorted  to get value like [(5,"we")]so that we can apply sortByKey operation on that.

**sortByKey([ascending], [numTasks])    When called on a dataset of (K, V) pairs where K implements Ordered, returns a dataset of (K, V) pairs sorted by keys in ascending or descending order, as specified in the boolean ascending argument.**

Reference [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html)